# How to prompt user when he tries to move out of any component in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a payment page with payment component as -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PayPalConfig, PayPalEnvironment, PayPalIntegrationType } from 'ngx-paypal';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { Payment } from '../models/payment.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment',
  templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css']
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {
//totalpay:number;
payment:Payment;
changesSaved=false;
  constructor(private appservice:AppService,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initConfig();

   }




hasChanges(){
  return true;

}   }
```

Now I want to prompt user if he tries to move back or try to click any link ,without clicking on paypal payment button in payment component ,I have used Candeactivate by making paymentguard.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
    import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router'; 
    import { PaymentComponent } from './payment/payment.component';
     import { PaymentGuard} from './payment/payment.guard';


    @Injectable() 
    export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<PaymentComponent> {

         canDeactivate(target: PaymentComponent) { 
              if (target.hasChanges()) { 
                   return window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?'); 
              } 
              return true; 
          } 
    }
```

> And this is my routing in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { BestsellersComponent } from './bestsellers/bestsellers.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { BenefitComponent } from './benefit/benefit.component';
import { CombinedComponent } from './combined/combined.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
import { StorageServiceModule} from 'angular-webstorage-service';
import { FormsModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { NgxPayPalModule } from 'ngx-paypal';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { PaymentComponent } from './payment/payment.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { FinalstatusComponent } from './finalstatus/finalstatus.component';
import { ConfirmDeactivateGuard } from './payment.guard';
import { PaymentfailComponent } from './paymentfail/paymentfail.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '', component: CombinedComponent },

  { path: 'payment', component: PaymentComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],canDeactivate[ConfirmDeactivateGuard]},
  { path: 'orderstatus', component: FinalstatusComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'paymentfail', component: PaymentfailComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    BestsellersComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    BenefitComponent,
    CombinedComponent,
    CartComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    PaymentComponent,
    FinalstatusComponent,
    PaymentfailComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    StorageServiceModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxPayPalModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot()

  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't know why it is not working ,any idea how to achieve it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CanDeactivate route guard must return one of: boolean, Promise, Observable.

In your case, it is best you use the later because your rely on the user taking an action to decide if CanDeactivate care run or not. This makes your guard asynchronous.

Because the method must always return the same type, the !hasChanges() myst also return an observable.

Try this code below:

```js
import { Observable, create } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router'; 
import { PaymentComponent } from './payment/payment.component';
import { PaymentGuard} from './payment/payment.guard';

@Injectable() 
export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<PaymentComponent> {
  canDeactivate(target: PaymentComponent): Observable<boolean> { 
    return Observable.create(function(observer) {
      if (!target.hasChanges()) {
        observer.next(true);
      } else if(window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?')) {
        observer.next(true);
      } else {
        observer.next(false);
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

I hope this helps!

**Edit:** I moved everything inside of the observer

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is happening? Like, do you get any error in the console?

Comment: there is no error but i am not getting the desired results :(

Comment: do i have to change hasChanges function too?

Comment: As you have it hardcoded right now, it should at least show the dialog. I will have to run this example to see the cause of the issue.

Comment: @LOGAN I see that you accepted the solution, I take it it worked?